# How to remove entity only if not used anymore?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

Is it possible to delete a `@ManyToOne` entity only if it is not referenced by any parent object anymore?

```
@Entity
public class Product {
     @ManyToOne
     private MyEntity entity;
}

@Entity
public class MyEntity {
  @Id
  private long id;

  private String name;
}
```

Is it possible that when `Product` gets remove, `MyEntity` should remain in the database. BUT if the product to be deleted is the last one that has a reference to the `MyEntity` id, *then* also delete the entity.

Comment: How do you mean _last_? Should your association be many-to-one?

Comment: Sorry, indeed this way a typo and it should be `@ManyToOne`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can delete orphans:

```
@OneToOne(orphanRemoval = true)
private MyEntity entity;
```

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/CascadeType.html

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such a thing in Hibernate.

You have to implement the check yourself and explicitly delete the entity if nothing else references it.